# Install a Dictionary Module in Python - WIndows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, module

I want to use all the word in an existing specific Dictionary and create a md5 hash out of it.

How will I import a dictionary in Windows 10 from Python program? 
Do I have to install a module?
Or just read a file that contains list of words in a dictionary? If yes, how will I get that file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this with any text file you like..

```
import hashlib
dict_fn = '/usr/share/dict/american-english'
with open(dict_fn) as f:
    text = f.read()
text = text.encode('utf-8')
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(text)
print(m.hexdigest())
```

This will give your the same results as `md5sum /usr/share/dict/american-english`

Note that the dictionary I reference is on Ubuntu and so is the md5sum command line program.

Comment: Thanks. Did you manually download the dictionary? What site did you download it?

Comment: No.  Ubuntu 18.04 had it already installed in the above location.

Comment: The package is referenced at... http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/american-english.5.html

Comment: Ah ok, Im using Windows 10 now. Can I use it in my OS?

Comment: You'll have to hunt around to find a copy of the file but it's open source so yes, you can use it under Windows.  If you have WSL (Widows Subsystem Linux - aka the Bash program) installed you can probably install the package for it, if you can figure out the package name.  WSL also has md5sum installed if that's useful to you.

Comment: BTW... The "hashlib" library is a native python library so you should have it in Windows (ie.. the above code will work fine on Windows).  The dictionary is the only thing that was Ubuntu specific but you can copy in any file for use.

Comment: Ah ok, Thanks. I have to find first a dictionary file to test your code. Thanks anyway.